# Animate the div affix to the top on scroll down

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I looked all over the web, probably not good enough, i am looking for this,
I want a div, top 100px and when I scroll a little down it has to animate to the top and stay sticky and reverse, so scroll up move animated to top 100px.

How can i achieve that?

Comment: Please provide proper explanation of your problem.

Comment: Can you please provide an image or code to refer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code snippet for animating div affix to top when scroll down and reverse when scroll back to top

```css
    body {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .affix {
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      
      -webkit-transition: top 0.5s ease-in-out;
      -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s;
      transition: top 0.5s ease-in-out;
      transition-delay: 0.5s;
      z-index: 9999 !important;
    }
    
    .navbar {
      margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    
    nav {
      top:100px;
      -webkit-transition: top 1s ease-in-out;
      -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s;
      transition: top 1s ease-in-out;
      transition-delay: 0.5s;
    }
    
    .affix ~ .container-fluid {
      position: relative;
      top: 50px;
    }
    
    #section1 {
      padding-top: 50px;
      height: 10px;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #fff;
    }
    
    #section2 {
      padding-top: 50px;
      height: 500px;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #673ab7;
    }
    
    #section3 {
      padding-top: 50px;
      height: 500px;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #ff9800;
    }
    
    #section41 {
      padding-top: 50px;
      height: 500px;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #00bcd4;
    }
    
    #section42 {
      padding-top: 50px;
      height: 500px;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #009688;
    }
```

```html
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">

  <div class="container-fluid" style="height:100px;">
    <img height="222" width="100%" src="https://bgcdn.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/5-2-God-is-in-Nature.jpg" alt="image">
  </div>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>

  </nav>

  <div id="section1" class="container-fluid">

    
  </div>
  <div id="section2" class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Section 2</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section3" class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Section 3</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section41" class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Section 4 Submenu 1</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section42" class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Section 4 Submenu 2</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>

</body>
```

Here is a plunker link for the same https://plnkr.co/edit/hTIXunKUjRtSE2kvsI2l?p=preview

I hope it works for you.

Comment: Wow, almost Pooja! If i scroll down, websitename move up, when its on top it goes down and up. Is it possible when you scrol down, direct, the websitename div moves up with animate? en when you scoll down back to the start point, top 100.

Comment: yes, by removing the transition and transition-delay css for nav like this https://plnkr.co/edit/Tq2WTNbETj23QyYeLagY?p=preview